# Do kernel keepalive automatically trigger? Or do I have to trigger them from the code?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

The kernel provides settings such as "tcp_keepalive_time", "tcp_keepalive_intvl", "tcp_keepalive_probes" ... do these probes work automatically? Or do I have to do something in my code to actually activate?

Comment: You have to enable keepalive on the socket. It is off by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify TCP keep alive on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24428598/608639) and [Configuring TCP keepalive after accept](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31426420/608639)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable these values on the socket. For example in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

void set_tcp_keepalive (int fd)
{
    int val;

    val = 1;
    if (setsockopt (fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &val, sizeof (val)) == -1) {
        perror ("setsockopt(SO_KEEPALIVE)");
    }

    val = 60;
    if (setsockopt (fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &val, sizeof (val)) == -1) {
        perror ("setsockopt(TCP_KEEPIDLE)");
    }

    val = 30;
    if (setsockopt (fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, &val, sizeof (val)) == -1) {
        perror ("setsockopt(TCP_KEEPINTVL)");
    }

    val = 2;
    if (setsockopt (fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, &val, sizeof (val)) == -1) {
        perror ("setsockopt(TCP_KEEPCNT)");
    }
}
```